# How to convert Nested JSON to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have the following nested json:

```
import requests

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    r = requests.get("...API DATA...")
    [
        {
            "ticker":"btcusd",
            "baseCurrency":"btc",
            "quoteCurrency":"usd",
            "priceData":[
                {
                    "open":3914.749407813885,
                    "high":3942.374263716895,
                    "low":3846.1755315352952,
                    "close":3849.1217299601617,
                    "date":"2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                    "tradesDone":756.0,
                    "volume":339.68131616889997,
                    "volumeNotional":1307474.735327181
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I would like to convert it into Pandas data frame. I have been able to do this:

```
j = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(j)
df
```

Output:

[image: output]

I would like to also expand 'priceData' in columns.

I have tried different methods, including json.normalise and json.loads, but there was always an error I could not understand.

Could please anyone show me how to do it in order to understand?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

priceData contains more than 1 element.

"ticker", "baseCurrency", and "quoteCurrency" are not essentially needed in the data frame, hence can be discarded.

[image: part of json elements]

Comment: Would you please add more detail for priceData? Is it always list with 1 element? How about the json? Is it always list with 1 element?

Comment: priceData has more than 1 element. 'Ticker', 'baseCurrency', and 'quoteCurrency' are not needed at all and might be discarded. Thanks @SatrioAdiPrabowo t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_normalize`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.json_normalize(data,'priceData',['ticker','baseCurrency','quoteCurrency'])
```

where,

```
data = [
    {
        "ticker":"btcusd",
        "baseCurrency":"btc",
        "quoteCurrency":"usd",
        "priceData":[
            {
                "open":3914.749407813885,
                "high":3942.374263716895,
                "low":3846.1755315352952,
                "close":3849.1217299601617,
                "date":"2019-01-02T00:00:00+00:00",
                "tradesDone":756.0,
                "volume":339.68131616889997,
                "volumeNotional":1307474.735327181
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Edit: *for multiple API calls***

```
final_data = []
for _ in range(3): ## how ever many times you want to call the API
    ## get you data from each API call
    final_data.extend(data)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I also have another question: if I want to make more than 1 API request which will have the same json format but different data (i.e., just changing the date to get more data), is there a way to concatenate these requests before doing json_normalize?

Comment: why not do `json_normalize` and then `pd.concat` afterwards?

Comment: Yes I can do it thank you but I think it will be very mechanical as I will have to make many API calls, then json.normalise all of them and then pd.concat. I was wondering if it was possible to make all the API calls in one request and then just json.normalise once.

Comment: Well, since *data* is a `list` you can also do `list.extend` - so, a `final_list = []` and then at every turn you do a `final_list.extend(data)`

Comment: Based on this answer, does it mean that if we want to include all json elements to form dataframe columns (and not just the outer elements in the json), we need to know those element names and mention them explicitly in the code?
Is there a way to do this without (say) writing priceData, ticker, etc.? In my case the json has about a thousand elements and different non-uniform nesting levels (for me it goes to nesting upto five levels - in the question it goes upto two).

Comment: If it's more complex, I suggest you add your own question, but may be link this one to show how related they are